# R - dump() to an object instead of a file

Tags: r

This question may be a bit more general in nature than just around dump(), but my specific application uses dump().

I want to take an nnet() model object, turn it into ascii and store it in another object.

```
y = runif(1000)
x1 = rnorm(1000)
x2 = rnorm(1000)
model = nnet(y~x1+x2,size=10)
textModel = dump("model")
```

The problem, is that `textModel` is equal to `"model"` not an ascii representation of the object `model`
dump() and dput() and other functions like this require a file to be specified.  I have working code to read in a file that's been output and parse/evaluate it, but this is going to be used in a foreach() loop and I cannot rely on channels to external files.  Instead, I want to create a data.frame which will store some reference details and the ascii representation of the model object.

Is there a way to bypass the need of dump() to write to a file and instead write directly to an object in R?

Comment: you could use a list?

Comment: The problem seems to be your "working code". Parsing/evaluating code saved as text is usually bad practice. Reconsider your approach.

Comment: @Roland - I appreciate that eval(parse()) is generally a bad idea, but this will not allow for arbitrary execution of code, eventually the code will be stored in a database for retrieval.  I want to fit a model, store it and re-execute it without refitting it.  If there's a better way to do that, I'd love to know.

Comment: @rawr How would a list help?

Comment: @Roland - the same basic problem still exists - how do store the results of saveRDS to an object instead of a file? I need to take thousands of models and in one step be able to write them all to a database.

Comment: `mylist <- list(model = nnet(y~x1+x2, size = 10))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways. Maybe someone with more experience with databases will show it.

Anyway, you can always capture the `dput` output:

```
x <- capture.output(dput(iris))
eval(parse(text=paste(x, collapse="\n")))
```

Of course if you do this thousands of times, it's very likely to be slow.

Comment: This is excellent - I changed it to `capture.output(dump("model",file=""))` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Mark I have to reiterate: This is bad practice. Try following rawr's idea.

Comment: The thing about rawr's idea is that it doesn't store the model outside of R.  We need to store the model outside of R, outside of a local file so that multiple systems can all use the same model without having to refit it.  I have 6 different R servers, each with different purposes and any or all of them could need to use these models.  If I store it in a file, I have to migrate the file (and fill out paperwork) to each server and hard code in references to the location. Storing as text in SQL makes the model server agnostic and far more portable. Is there another solution like this?